# What is the correct way to assign Parent's static field values to Child's non-static field values?

Tags: java

I'm new to programming so please excuse me if my question sounds stupid. However, following is what I want to do. *(Currently I'm learning about Java's Comparable and Cloneable Interfaces)*

I was testing how Cloneable and Comparable Interface works in java and created these two classes for that purpose:

Class 1 --> Abstract Class --> GeometricShapes

Class 2 --> Non-Abstract   --> Circle

I was trying to create different objects of the Circle class with unique IDs.

Following is my code for both the classes. While, I'm able to achieve what I wanted to but vsCode is giving a warning *"The static field GeometricShapes.id should be accessed in a static way"*. So I know this is not the best way to do what I'm trying to do.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

**Codes:**

```
public abstract class GeometricShapes {
protected static int id = 0;
protected String colour;
protected boolean filled;
protected java.util.Date creationDate;

protected GeometricShapes(String colour, boolean filled) {
    id++;
    creationDate = new java.util.Date();
    this.colour = colour;
    this.filled = filled;
}

protected abstract double getArea();

protected abstract double getPerimeter();
```

}

```
public class Circle extends GeometricShapes implements Comparable<Circle>, Cloneable {

private double radius;
private int circleID = super.id; //This is where the problem is

public double getRadius() {
    return this.radius;
}

public Circle(String colour, boolean filled, double radius) {
    super(colour, filled);
    this.radius = radius;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Circle arg0) {
    if (this.radius > arg0.radius)
        return 1;
    else if (this.radius < arg0.radius)
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}

@Override
public double getArea() {
    return ((this.radius * this.radius) * Math.PI);
}

@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    return (2 * Math.PI) * this.radius;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ("Circle id: \t" + this.circleID + "\nCreated on: \t" + this.creationDate + "\nRadius: \t" + this.radius
            + "\nArea: \t\t" + this.getArea() + "\nPerimtr: \t" + this.getPerimeter());
}

public java.util.Date getCreationDate() {
    return this.creationDate;
}

public int getID() {
    return this.circleID;
}
```

}

Comment: private int circleID = super.id; Is where the problem lies. Any better solution?

Comment: why are you using a static field anyway, just use a non static field, because the Id will be the same on every child even though they might be in different Objects.

Comment: No, the IDs are different for each instance of the Circle object. It starts with 1 and then keep increasing by 1 for each new instance.

Comment: I used "private int circleID = GeometricShapres.id;" and this solves the problem of alert about the static non-static referencing but is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: There is at least one other way to do it but this is one correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Define two fields related to Id number generation. Define one `static` field which indicates the next Id to use when a new object is created. This value increases which each new instance. Define another non-`static` field for the actual Id of that specific instance.

```
public abstract class GeometricShapes {
    /**
     * Field for the next Id to use.
     */
    private static int nextIdToUse = 1;

    /**
     * The Id of this geometric shape.
     */
    private final int id;

    protected GeometricShapes(String colour, boolean filled) {
        this.id = nextIdToUse++;
        // [...]
    }

    /**
     * Returns the Id of this geometric shape.
     *
     * @return The Id.
     */
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```